# HTML+CSS Layout with 3 rows, middle row fluid sandwiched by fixed height rows

Tags: html, css

I am wondering if there is a pure html+css way to specify a 3 row layout where the middle div is greedy and takes up all the remaining height that the two fixed rows leave behind.  In XAML this would be the asterisk (*) character.  Ex.  `<row height="*"></row>`  which tells the rendering engine that this row will consume all remaining height offered by its parent.

I want the total height to take up all screen height (with no vertical scrolling).

```
<body style="height:100%">
   <header style="height: 64px"> </header>

   <div style="height: *"> </div>

   <footer style="height: 64px"> </footer>
</body>
```

When the browser screen is resized, the middle content should fluctuate but the header and footer should remain same height fixed.

Comment: Google flexbox and see if it fits your needs. I'm not quite into this, so I can't provide a full answer.

Comment: @Mr. Alien: Can't seem to come up with the correct search terms

Comment: @JayPrime2012: Try the article on smashingmagazine instead: http://coding.smashingmagazine.com/2013/05/22/centering-elements-with-flexbox/

Comment: @kleinfreund Thanks for link.  Flexbox is IE10+ so not really viable for another couple years.  Next you say polyfills?  Blah, I gotta draw the line somewhere.  Flexbox isn't ready to go yet.  Plus the specification changes really sucks things up as well.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This can be achiever quite easily with absolute positioning in CSS.

```
* {
  margin:0;
}
header {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:64px;
  top:0;
}
footer {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  height:64px;
  bottom:0;
}
div {
  position:absolute;
  width:100%;
  top:64px;
  bottom:64px;
}
```

Note, that in real code you'll want to use a class for the inner div otherwise you'll be styling all the div elements.

Here's a more complete fiddle example: http://jsfiddle.net/BMxzn/

Comment: How do you think this answers the question in any way? This is the opposite of what behavior the author wants to achieve. absolutely positioned elements are removed from the document flow and other elemens can't act relatively to them.

Comment: @kleinfreund My understanding is that any other elements would be children of the header, footer or inner div, which is no problem for absolutely positioned elements. It's not like he can position anything around these elements if the header is fixed height, the footer is fixed height and the inner div uses up all the remaining space.

Comment: I was originally thinking what kleinfreund said till i read the code and it does seem like since all my content would go into one of these 3, the absolute positioning will not be a problem.  I'll see if I can make this work...

Comment: One will have massive problems with a layout based on absolutely positioned containers.

Comment: @JamesHolderness  Perhaps you can help me... I'm trying to get the content "div" that is within the "div" with the absolute positioning to be height: 100% but if I do that it seems to just ignore the footer and it makes the height the size of the body height, rather than size of its containing div height...

Comment: @JayPrime2012 Can you provide a jsfiddle link with an example of what you mean? 100% height should work - I can't reproduce your problem.

Comment: It was error in my markup.  I have to do this sandwhich layout in a view within the content of the sandwich layout, and I think at that point this absolute positioning way will crumble.  Correct?

Comment: As long as the view containing the sandwich layout has a height of some sort, it should work. Also make sure you've set `position:relative` on the containing view to make sure its children are positioned relative to it, rather than the outer div. You could also use `position:absolute` if that is more appropriate for what you want to do - just don't leave it without any positioning.

Comment: This is really the answer in today's web.  However much it sucks.

Answer (score 3):

Try this

css

```
html, body{
    height:100%;    
}

header{
    height:64px;
    background-color:#0C9;
}
footer{
    height:64px;
    background-color:#666;
}
.bodyPan{
    height: calc(100% - 128px); 
}
```

html

```
<header> </header>

<div class="bodyPan"> </div>

<footer> </footer>
```

[jsFiddle File](http://jsfiddle.net/dk2fw/)

Comment: This is pretty awesome.  It is for IE9+.  Unfortunately I'm targetting IE8+.  A fallback using percent can be specified, so I might take this route because I have to do this sandwhich type of layout scheme in views within views.  So the absolute positioning way will be troublesome...

Comment: for IE8+ you have to use jquery to calculate the window's height

Answer (score 0):

You could also use `box-sizing:border-box` to do this.

```
div
{
    height: 100%;
    background: pink;
    margin-top: -64px;
    padding-top: 64px;

    margin-bottom: -64px;
    padding-bottom: 64px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

Incidentally, it has better browser support than calc. (IE8+ and all modern browsers)

[Also notice that for firefox you need to prefix the box-sizing prop with -moz- ]

[**FIDDLE**](http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/PGC7D/2/)

Answer (score 0):

Danield solution is the best cross-browser solution but remember to add to :

```
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
```