# Cannot get textarea to be 100% height of remaining DIV space

Tags: html, css, textarea

I need your help. For some reason or another, it appears that my textarea does not want to cooperate. What I would like to do, is to expand its height to 100% of the space left in the DIV per the red arrow depicted below. But maybe I am doing something wrong. Perhaps a fresh set of eyes would great help.

[image]

Here is the HTML and CSS in question:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

<style type="text/css">
.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
</style>


</head>

<body>

<div class="content">

    <div>text here</div>

    <div><textarea></textarea></div>

    <div><input type="button" value="Click Me"/></div>


</div>


</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Have a look at the answer to [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16917340/htmlcss-layout-with-3-rows-middle-row-fluid-sandwiched-by-fixed-height-rows) for positioning the 3 rows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can get rid of unnecessary divs and do like that:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>

  <style type="text/css">
    .content {
      width: 500px;
      height: 500px;
      border: 1px solid blue;
    }
    
    textarea {
      width: 100%;
      height: calc(100% - 45px);
      box-sizing: border-box;
    }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <div class="content">
    <div>text here</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div>
      <input type="button" value="Click Me" />
    </div>
  </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: There are lots of ways to apparently skin a cat. But this example seems to also satisfy the needs of rendering this possible in IE so this answer will take the cake. Thank you all for your dedication and support!

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you set the height of `textarea` to be `100%` of its parent. But its parent has `height: auto`, so its height depends on its contents. That's a recursive definition.

You can solve it by setting an explicit height to that parent, e.g. `100%`. But then the sum of heights of the contents of `.content` would be more than `100%`.

If you know the height of the other contents of `.content` you can use `calc()`.

But if you want a fluid layout, you should can CSS tables.

```css
.content { display: table }
.content > div { display: table-row }
.content > div:nth-child(2) { height: 100% }
```

Additionally, some browsers may require absolute positioning in order to take the `textarea` out-of-flow and thus avoid a recursive definition of the height.

```css
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: table;
  table-layout: fix
}
.content > div {
  display: table-row;
  position: relative;
}
.content > div:nth-child(2) {
  height: 100%; /* As much as possible */
}
textarea {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>text here</div>
  <div><textarea></textarea></div>
  <div><input type="button" value="Click Me" /></div>
</div>
```

But better remove the wrapper of `textarea` and use flexbox:

```css
.content { display: flex; flex-direction: column; }
textarea { flex-grow: 1; }
```

```css
.content {
  width: 500px;
  height: 500px;
  border: 1px solid blue;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
}
textarea {
  flex-grow: 1;
}
```

```html
<div class="content">
  <div>text here</div>
  <textarea></textarea>
  <div><input type="button" value="Click Me" /></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Get the textarea out of div and use flexbox: https://jsfiddle.net/Lqtuprpu/

```
<div class="content">
    <div>text here</div>
    <textarea></textarea>
    <div><input type="button" value="Click Me"/></div>
</div>


.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
}
textarea {
    flex-basis: 100%;
    flex-shrink: 1;
    width: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

More info about flexbox usage: https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/a-guide-to-flexbox/

Answer (score 0):

There is a simple and sweet trick. Set `textarea` position as `absolute` while top and left are 0, then set wrapper div position as relative. That's all.

In this case you are not enforced to set a certain height in px for wrapper

```css
.content {
    width: 500px;
    height: 500px;
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
textarea {
    width: 100%;
    height: 100%;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
}
.wrapper{
    position: relative;
    height: calc(100% - 40px);
}
```

```html
<div class="content">

    <div style="height: 20px">text here</div>

    <div class="wrapper">
        <textarea></textarea>
    </div>

    <div style="height: 20px"><input type="button" value="Click Me"/></div>
</div>
```

or textarea.